# Why the SPFX Application customizer extension only run on modern pages, without running on modern list views

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I have created a new SPFX, with these settings:-

- Which type of client-side component to create? **Extension**
- Which type of client-side extension to create? **Application Customizer**

and i added the SPFX app inside my site collection, but I noted that the SPFX will only run inside modern pages, but it will not run inside modern list views and other modern application pages.. so is this normal? or I can modify the SPFX to run on all the site's pages and list views as well?

Thanks

Comment: Does your code render in the placeholders described here? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions

Comment: @CallumCrowley i followed the steps in this link https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

Comment: Are you viewing the list from the list itself or via the list view web part?

Comment: @CallumCrowley  from the list itself